# Some questions about NEHotspotHelper

Tags: ios9, networkextension

I have applied for the permission to NEHotspotHelper successfully，and it had been used in my project.
[see OpenWrt-5G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpa59.jpg)
It works,but I found some problems on the connection.
I found sometimes password input box will pop up even though the password I set was correct.
[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ORpq.jpg)
But it can be connected successfully after several attempts.
This problem has been bothering me for a long time.
I do not know if anyone else had encountered this problem.
I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this bug as [rdar://27638199](http://www.openradar.me/27638199)
I found it hard to reproduce, I had observed since iOS 9.0 but never managed to reproduce it and log it somewhat consistently until recently.

When this happens, you see lines on the system log saying something like:

`<Warning>: __37-[WiFiManager beginCaptivePlugInScan]_block_invoke: Error: unable to find (ssid) in _networks`

I thought it may have something to do with the phone scanning on different bands, and by the time the response to `kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeFilterScanList` is delivered, `_networks` contains a different set of networks.